# Help with the last step in proving Hardy–Littlewood maximal inequality

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I'm following the proof of the [Hardy–Littlewood maximal inequality on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function#Proof) and I'm having trouble with the last step. It says that

$$2C_p\int_{t = 0}^{\infty}{\int_{|f| > t/2}{t^{p - 2}|f|dx}dt} = C_p \| f \|_p^p$$

I am not seeing how to justify this. I feel like there is something simple here but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a VERY back-of-the-envelope calculation. But I think the general idea is to use Fubini theorem to flip the order of integration:

[image]

Comment: This seems correct to me, thanks!. I was having trouble seeing how the bounds of integration changed when we change the order of integration. If you want to type it out in MathJax, I can make this the correct answer. Up to you.